# Checkstyle Command Line Change Property

Tags: java, command-line, jar, checkstyle

**We can use Checkstyle directly using the `.jar` file and from the command line. But how can we modify the property if we use Google java style or any other configuration file from the `.jar` file only?**

**Example
 -**
`java -jar checkstyle-8.37-all.jar -c /google_checks.xml JAVA_FILE_PATH`,
 In this case, I want to update the `severity` property which is by default `warn` in `google_checks.xml` and I want to update it to `error`.

As per the command line usage [here](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/cmdline.html#Command_line_usage) from the documentation, the correct way to access the property in command is 
`-D<property>=<value>`.

And what I am trying is
 `java -Dcheckstyle.api.SeverityLevel=error -jar checkstyle-8.37-all.jar -c /google_checks.xml JAVA_FILE_PATH`
which is not working.